# Как интегрировать backend в React

Tags: create-react-app

Начинаю изучать React, и нигде не могу найти гайд, как сделать интеграцию готового бэкенда. Везде разные примеры, как что и почему именно так пишется index.js бекенд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const FetchBackend = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setState(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Server data fetching</h1>
      {state &&
        state.map(({ id, name, email }) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              Name: {name}
              E-mail: {email}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FetchBackend;
```

Поставь лайк если этот код работает )

Comment: Хороший простой пример. При реальном использовании еще обработку ошибок  и POST-ы скорее всего добавлять к этому надо будет.